# Best Analysis Method on Understanding the Driving Factor of Math Scores: PCA?

Tags: python, categorical-data, methodology

I'm looking to understand the best way to understand the factors that drive student math scores. I have each data such as (not limited to) demographics, parent's education level (categorical), taking after-school math program (0/1, yes or no), hours spent on sports per week (numeric). I don't intend to do any prediction and just want to know what factors can be the drivers of the student math scores.

I was initially planning to use factor analysis but realized that I have categorical variables.

Comment: typically this would be done with linear regression. But it will be possibly difficult to analyse because of correlations between your variables